# Retrieving records from mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have 2 different databases that are linked with a primary key that appears in both tables which is "id".

Different Id's in database have different records.

I have a button that when clicked pulling everything from both database tables, but they all appear in a table with all records stacked on top of each other in td cells.

something like this:

```
Id----name----address---grade1----grade2---grade3---
Id----name----address---grade1----grade2---grade3---
Id----name----address---grade1----grade2---grade3---
Id----name----address---grade1----grade2---grade3---
Id----name----address---grade1----grade2---grade3---
Id----name----address---grade1----grade2---grade3---
```

I would like for them to print out in following format:

```
ID - xxxxxx
name - xxxxxxx
address - xxxxxxx
```

table of grades associated with id (multiple rows, 4 columns)

```
ID - xxxxxx
name - xxxxxxx
address - xxxxxxx
```

table of grades associated with id (multiple rows, 4 columns)

```
ID - xxxxxx
name - xxxxxxx
address - xxxxxxx
```

table of grades associated with id (multiple rows, 4 columns

This is the PHP code

```
<style> table, td, caption { border: 2px solid black ; padding: 10px; } </style>
<style> td { border: 1px solid green ; width: 100px;} </style>
<style> caption { color: green ; } </style>

<?php
include ("../../php/account.php");
$dbh = mysql_connect ( $hostname, $username, $password )
                   or die ( "Unable to connect to MySQL database" );
mysql_select_db( $project );

$s="SELECT * from newstudent, grades where newstudent.id=grades.id";  
($t=mysql_query($s)) or die('Error! Student not found!');

print "<table>";
print "<caption>"; 
print "Grade report for all the Registered Students";
print "</caption>";
print "<tr> <th>Student ID</th> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th> <th>Email</th> <th>Course ID</th> <th>Grade One</th> <th>Grade Two</th> <th>Grade Three</th> <th>Total</th>";
//2. Get rows $r
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($t))
{
//3. Get columns of row $r["---"]
 print "<tr>";
 print "<td>";
 print $r["id"];
 print "</td>";

    print "<td>";
    print $r["firstname"];
    print "</td>";

    print "<td>";
    print $r["lastname"];
    print "</td>";

print "<td>";
print $r["email"];
print "</td>";



 print "<td>";
 print $r["subject"];
 print "</td>";

    print "<td>";
    print $r["gradeone"];
    print "</td>";

print "<td>";
print $r["gradetwo"];
print "</td>";

    print "<td>";
    print $r["gradethree"];
    print "</td>";

    print "<td>";
    print $r["Total"];
    print "</td>";

}
print "</table>";
```

Comment: Please _do no use_ the old and deprecated `mysql_` functions. Use `mysqli_` or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you want a sql query like this

```
SELECT * from newstudent as s inner join grades as g on s.id=g.id
```

but when i look to your code i think that you have to change your grade db i guess that you will have a lot of null values
i would make the grade table like this

id - student_id - grade

and link them on student_id